# Initialising nested arrays on the CUDA device

Tags: c++, cuda

I want to initialise an array of structs on the CUDA device, where each struct contains an array of doubles:

```
typedef struct TimeSeries
{
    double* values;
} TimeSeries;

TimeSeries* allTimeSeries;
```

I tried using CUDA managed memory to initialise the `allTimesSeries` array of structs, then initialise each `values` array of doubles.

Here's my minimal working example:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

#define cudaCheckErrors(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line)
{   
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        exit(code);
    }
}   

typedef struct TimeSeries
{
    double* values;
} TimeSeries;

void print_host(TimeSeries* all)
{
    printf("CPU %f %f\n", all[0].values[0], all[0].values[1]);
    printf("CPU %f\n", all[1].values[0]);
}

__global__ void print_device(TimeSeries* all)
{
    printf("GPU %f %f\n", all[0].values[0], all[0].values[1]);
    printf("GPU %f\n", all[1].values[0]);
}

int main()
{   
    TimeSeries* all;
    cudaCheckErrors(cudaMallocManaged(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&all),
            2*sizeof(TimeSeries)));

    cudaCheckErrors(cudaMallocManaged(
            reinterpret_cast<void**>(&(all[0].values)), 2*sizeof(double)));
    cudaCheckErrors(cudaMallocManaged(
            reinterpret_cast<void**>(&(all[1].values)), 1*sizeof(double)));

    all[0].values[0] = 4.8;
    all[0].values[1] = 3.3;
    all[1].values[0] = 0.4;

    print_host(all);
    print_device<<<1, 1>>>(all);

    cudaCheckErrors(cudaFree(all[0].values));
    cudaCheckErrors(cudaFree(all[1].values));
    cudaCheckErrors(cudaFree(all));

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with nvcc (CUDA 10) and running on a Tesla K80 gives:

```
CPU 4.800000 3.300000
CPU 0.400000

Command terminated
```

How can initialise this data without crashing the GPU?  I don't mind if the solution uses unified (managed) memory or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inevitably, I found the problem shortly after posting my question.  I needed to call `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` before calling `cudaFree()`:

```
print_host(all);
print_device<<<1, 1>>>(all);

cudaCheckErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

cudaCheckErrors(cudaFree(all[0].values));
cudaCheckErrors(cudaFree(all[1].values));
cudaCheckErrors(cudaFree(all));
```

I found the problem using the [cuda-gdb](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-gdb/index.html) debugger.

Comment: I don't understand why this would fix the problem; `cudaFree`is supposed to be synchronous, so calling `cudaDeviceSynchronize` right before `cudaFree` shouldn't have changed anything. Does your kernel return an error code in either case?

Comment: Does `cudaFree` implicitly synchronize with the device?  Like you, I assume that it should.  Or perhaps I needed to `cudaDeviceSynchronize` immediately after initialising the `all` array?

Comment: I guess that it might not; I assumed that it synchronizes because there's no stream argument, which is what I would expect if I wanted to permit asynchronous memory management. But I don't really know